# What happened to the blog post "Closing questions: how do we compare?"

Tags: support, blog

What happened to the blog post [*Closing questions: how do we compare?*](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2013/02/closing-questions-how-do-we-compare/) from February 2013?

I have found a link to this blog post [on another meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8703/academic-integrity/8715#8715) where it was mentioned as a source of an [interesting graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKTu6.jpg) comparing percentage of closed questions on various websites. When I wanted to see whether this blog post contains more details about how the data were obtained, I found out that the post does not exists.

Google search for ["closing-questions-how-do-we-compare"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22closing-questions-how-do-we-compare%22) shows that this blog post have been mentioned on this site's twitter account and in chat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I removed it because the data I collected were incorrect, so the conclusions I drew were incorrect.

This comment from Shog9 explains the problem:

> Hey, Matt… You neglected to limit your query to questions – since answers can’t be closed, that skews the numbers considerably. See: http://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/98700/closed-questions-from-2012-by-score
>
> Also, ~20% of questions on EL&U have been deleted, many of which were closed as well – since those aren’t public, they tend to skew the numbers also.

I haven't taken the time to get the correct data, so I've not put the post back up.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!